# Getting ACF Field in Page - From the Footer

Tags: pages, advanced-custom-fields, block-editor, footer

I'm trying to get ACF field that is part of an ACF block in a *Page* I've created, say "Home Page". I'm trying to do this from the footer, but with no success.

I've tried the following:

I got the "post" id (despite it's a page) from the url in the admin console: 
`/wp-admin/post.php?post=7&action=edit`. My code may seem strange, it's a php blade template, I'm using Root.io Sage theme.

```
{{ the_field('hours-o-mo', 7) }}
```

and

```
@php
    the_field('hours-o-mo', 7) 
@endphp
```

I haven't "registered" any blocks, per se, I'm just using this plugin ( https://github.com/MWDelaney/sage-acf-wp-blocks ) to make template-only acf blocks, that automatically show in my Gutenberg page builder.

I've also tried `get_field`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, it should be simple to get an ACF field from a specific page, from the footer. Right?

Comment: Are you sure the field name is `hours-o-mo` and that the post has a value for that field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue, the acf get_field() function in footer returned null. Native WP function get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'option_key', true ) didn't work to. But when I've noticed that get_the_ID() function in footer returned the wrong value because I forgot to reset query after custom WP_Query. So, reset custom WP_Query (wp_reset_query()) or hard code the page ID.